# Can I use an anchor in an href to scroll to a location with classname and no id?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

i'm using Javascript and I need an anchor to a classname cause we don't have id near the location. Can I use an anchor in an href tag to doing this?

The example is of an anchor with id's use:

```
<div id='anchorID'>
<a href='mysite.com#anchorID>
```

But can I do this if I have only classname? With anchor, not scrollInToView or something else:

```
<div class='myclass'>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need an id or additional javascript for this.

Comment: No, this does not work with a class. It needs to refer to an ID, or the name of a specific element.

Comment: Is it necessary for the URL to display this anchor? If not read about [scrollToView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). If you need the url to display the anchor, then `id` or `name` attributes are your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary for the URL to display this anchor? If not read about [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

If you need the url alone to accomplish the navigation, then `id` or `name` attributes (on the element itself) are your only options.

BTW, a nice visual effect for smoothly scrolling to a functioning anchor can be accomplished with a CSS property called [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior):

```
html
{
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

This has nothing to do with your issue, but I thought you might like it.

Answer (score 0):

only Href does not work with class. you can do with javascript/jQuery

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' data-target='.myClass'>Link</a>
```

jQuery

```
$("[data-target]").on('click', function(){
   var target_  = $(this).attr("data-target");
   var targetSelector = $(target_);
   if(targetSelector.length){
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: targetSelector.offset().top }, 1000);
   }
})
```